# Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ParseObject

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-listview

I'm having some trouply with my application using Parse. In order to populate a LitsView with parse objects, I have used the following adapter class. The problem is, i get an error at

```
ParseObject statusObject = mStatus.get(position);
```

The error reads: Error:(44, 47) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to ParseObject

What's happening here?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseObject;

import java.util.List;

public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
protected Context mContext;
protected List mStatus;

public StatusAdapter(Context context, List status) {
    super(context, R.layout.homepage, status);
    mContext = context;
    mStatus = status;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.homepage, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.usernameHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.usernameHP);
        holder.statusHomepage = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.statusHP);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    ParseObject statusObject = mStatus.get(position);

    // title
    String username = statusObject.getString("user");
    holder.usernameHomepage.setText(username);

    // content
    String status = statusObject.getString("newStatus");
    holder.statusHomepage.setText(status);

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView usernameHomepage;
    TextView statusHomepage;

}

}
```

Comment: check what mStatus.get(position) is returning

Comment: You are getting this problem because `get` method by default returns `Object` so you should either cast the result or use generic version of `List`. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using generic list (`List<E>`). Either you should cast object:

`ParseObject statusObject = (ParseObject) mStatus.get(position);`

or use a list like:
`protected List<ParseObject> mStatus;`

Then you will not need to caste it. You will also need to modify the contructor:

```
public StatusAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> status) {
    super(context, R.layout.homepage, status);
    mContext = context;
    mStatus = status;
}
```